# RecyclerView can not capture MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

when I set a `OnClickListener` on the `holder.itemView` in `onBindViewHolder()`, the `onTouchEvent()` in my `RecyclerView` can not capture `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`,

but it still can capture `ACTION_UP` and `MOVE`. 

Please help me how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a `setOnTouchListener` on the holder.itemView